# Searches the array of objects with an unknown number of parameters and is not known by which parameters the search is performed

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to write a pipe (angular 7) that gets an array parameters, whose length is unknown. The type of array is searchParamter that looks like this:

```
class SearchParam  {
      key: string;
      value: string[];
```

}

the function in Pseudo-code:

```
 transform(val: any[],args: SearchParam[]) {
for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {
    if (val[i].hasOwnProperty(args[j].key))
       for(k=0;k<args[j].value.length;k++)
           if(val[i].value==args[j].value[k].val)
              return val[i];
  }
 }
}
```

How should I write this by using the Array functions of js?
Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to achieve by piping array?

Comment: ^^^same questions. Also, I know you said it's pseudo code, but I hope you stop using forloops and jump to .maps and having 3 nestested forloops is very bad.

Comment: @TAMOStudio Certainly, it is only to make the question more clear and simple

Comment: @Tzof but what are you asking? the question isn't clear

Answer (score 0):

you can try following code for your transform function

```js
interface searchParam {
  key: string;
  values: string[];
}

const values: searchParam = [
  {key:'1', values: ['1','2','3']},
  {key:'2', values: ['1','2','3']},
  {key:'3', values: ['1','5','6']},
  {key:'3', values: ['1','2','3']},
  {key:'5', values: ['1','2','3']},
  {key:'6', values: ['1','2','3']},
];

const args: searchParam = [
    {key:'1', values: ['1','2','3']},
    {key:'3', values: ['1','5','6']},
];

function transform(val:searchParam[],args:searchParam[]){
  const result = [];
  for(let arg of args){
     const filtered = val.filter((e)=>{
       return e.key === arg.key &&
       e.values.every((ele,index)=>e.values[index] === arg.values[index]);
      });
     result.push(...filtered);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(transform(values,args));
```